# spark dataframe: merge tuples when an element matches

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe with the following datatype:

Name: string, array>

Here is sample data:

> cust1 [[0,elem1], [0,elem2], [0, elem3], [1, grp1], [1, grp2], [1, grp3], [1, grp4], [2, val10], [2, val20]]

I want to concat all the elements (while maintaining the order) that have the same first element of the tuple. For example (0, elem1) and (0, elem2) should be merged since the first element of the tuple is 0 (same).

Here is the desired o/p:

> cust1  [(0, [elem1, elem2, elem3]), (1,[grp1, grp2, grp3, grp4]), (2,[val10, val20])]

How do I do it using dataframe operations?

I tried the following:

```
  val reshape = udf((xs: Seq[Row]) => Row.fromSeq(Seq((_.getString(0), xs.groupBy(_.getString(0)).values.map(_.map(_.getString(1)).toArray).toArray)))
```

However, I get this error:

> error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) =>
>   x$1.getString(0))

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
val reshape = udf((xs: Seq[Row]) => xs.groupBy(_.getString(0)).values.map(_.map(_.getString(1)).toArray).toArray)

df.select(reshape(df.col("column"))
```

Comment: I have added another column to the dataframe, can you please update your answer.

Comment: I am able to add the additional column so that is not a problem. However, I would like to include the groupby key in the o/p as shown in the updated o/p.  Any thoughts on how to do that will be great.

Comment: I tried doing this:   val reshape = udf((xs: Seq[Row]) => Row.fromSeq(Seq((_.getString(0), xs.groupBy(_.getString(0)).values.map(_.map(_.getString(1)).toArray).toArray)))
but it gives me this error:  error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.getString(0))